# Override css styles in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created an application in React using ant design library. In my CSS file, I added some base styles:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I expect that these styles should override all styles, but they don't override antd styles. Inspecting the `p` tag in the console I noticed that these styles:

```css
 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
} /// comes from antd.css
```

overide my previous styles. How to fix this (to make my styles to override all styles) without using `!important`? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-create-react-app-forked-0vs14?file=/index.js:315-811

Comment: Where are you trying to override the styles? In CSS you can override styles by making the selector (the thing that says what element is affected) more _specific_. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @evolutionxbox, in styless.css i added the above code that should remove all margins, but antd styles override mine? how to fix?

Comment: yours should be loaded after the antd.css file

Comment: and if antd puts the styles on the p-tag you have to be more spcific, as 
evolutionxbox said

Comment: `p { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: @TheWuif, how to load antd styles after my styles?

Comment: i think that would not have any effect in your case, you just have to pay attention how css works, and its well explained here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ you cant get past this limits without using !important

Comment: `p` will always be more specific like `*`. but you may use `body * { ... }`. but don't know if this is valid

Comment: but overriding all styles in antd will be a bad idea anyway. it can lead to many problems. overriding `p` will be fine as it is predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This is how CSS works, since antd styles target directly the `p` tag, you selecting it via `*` won't have a higher importance unless you add behind it `html *` or `body *` or mark the styles as `!important`

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-create-react-app-forked-hlwnh?file=/styless.css:0-64) that I forked from yours.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `px` in number value

Based on antd github issue `You need to improve your CSS selector's specificity. And it's not a bug..` [Github Discussion](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4838)

```
p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: your answer does not work

Comment: It's work https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-create-react-app-forked-134qr?file=/styless.css

Comment: it will not work, as style is not specific. this way you can only stet styles that are not set more specific

Comment: You watch codesandbox that i send ?

Comment: you can set the padding, as it is not send via a `p` style, but you cant set the margin this way.

Comment: if you don't believe me, try to update the margin-bottom in your example to 50px ;)

Comment: @TheWuif or if the style is defined later in the cascade.

Comment: right, but only if it has the same level of specifity

Comment: @wisnuaryadipa now your answer is right ;)

Comment: @TheWuif Good to hear that :D